# svcutil get wsdl and xsd from dll

Tags: wcf

Launching in Command Prompt

```
svcutil "C:\Users\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WcfServiceLibrary1\WcfServiceLibrary1\bin\Debug\WcfServiceLibrary1.dll"
```

Output:

```
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.6.1055.0]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Generating metadata files...
C:\Windows\System32\tempuri.org.wsdl
C:\Windows\System32\tempuri.org.xsd
C:\Windows\System32\schemas.microsoft.com.2003.10.Serialization.xsd
C:\Windows\System32\WcfServiceLibrary1.xsd
```

But it seems that there are no any signs of files in `C:\Windows\System32\` where svcitul put them?

Interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }

    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    // You can add XSD files into the project. After building the project, you can directly use the data types defined there, with the namespace "WcfServiceLibrary1.ContractType".
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Implmentation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try specifying a target folder other than `c:\windows\system32`

Comment: it gererates the files in the folder you're running the prompt command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **svcutil** command in **C:\Windows\System32**, the files are created in **C:\Windows\SysWOW64**.

you could also use the **/directory** to assign the output folder.

here is official document.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.5/aa347733(v=vs.90)